# Trouble with a Trig Identity and Euler's Formula

Tags: trigonometry

I have the following expression

$\cos^2(s) + 2\sin^2(s)$

and need to show that it is equivalent to the following expression

$1 + \sin^2(s)$

I have no idea where to start, however. I'm familiar with the use of Euler's Formula to derive the angle addition and subtraction formulas--and from there, the double and half angle formulas.

Where do we start to go from the first statement above to the second? Can you tie the trig identities you use back to Euler's Formula?

Comment: Do you know the result of $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x $?

Comment: And in LaTeX don't use `\ ` to make spacing and use `\cos` and `\sin` upright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cos^2(x) + 2\sin^2(x) = \cos^2(x) + \underbrace{\sin^2(x) + \sin^2(x)}_{2\sin^2(x)}$$

Now, since $\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1$

you easily get

$$1 + \sin^2(x)$$

Comment: A complete solution leaves little for the asker to try or figure out on their own.

Comment: But is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you! I learned something. +1

Comment: @user21820 A complete solution sometimes opens the mind of the asker more than leaving him to guess and try for hours.

Comment: @user1739757 You're welcome!! Never forget about those "tricks" and important identities!

Comment: @HeliumAtom: In my experience as a teacher, that's simply not true. For **homework**, complete solutions are not desirable. Of course guessing and trying should always be kept at the limit of the student's ability, not further. Anyway, do what you like. If you teach long enough you'll perhaps change your mind.

Answer (score 0):

Always remember $\cos,\sin$ as the $x,y$ coordinates of a point on the unit circle. Then Pythagoras theorem tells you that the sum of their squares is $1$. And that solves a lot of such identities.

Comment: This kind of back-and-forth dialog is probably best done in chat.

Comment: @user1739757: That's very true, but usually it's better to show the crux of the matter rather than spoon-feed. Most students never learn to do mathematics on their own because they are never encouraged to try.